# Two signals alternately on the left and right of a frequency

Tags: rf, radio, ham-radio, software-defined-radio

I was listening to the [WebSDR](http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/) of Twente University, just outside the amateur band, and saw these signals. The x axis is frequency in kilohertz, the y axis is time, where the whole axis shown is about 15s.

[image]

It occurred to me that the two signals are alternately left and right of the line on 13,971kHz. Would that be a coincidence, or is this some kind of transmission technique? If the latter, how is it called and how does it work?

The line seems to be unrelated, it's still there although the signals are gone.

Comment: Is that a single-sideband FM transmission, perhaps? With the other sideband being used for some other transmission at the same time?

Comment: In the UK, 13.870-14.000 MHz is government use for aeronauticl, mobile and land mobile - maybe it is a two way comms with send and receive at different frequencies. What country are you in? Info from OFCOM.

Comment: @Andyaka the receiver is located in Twente, The Netherlands.

Comment: @Andyaka: It's kHz, not MHz. (Although I don't understand Camil's comment about "just outside the amateur band".)

Comment: @DaveTweed when you look at http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/, you can see that the specific frequency is just outside the 20m band as it's indicated by the green line. That's what I meant :)

Comment: @DaveTweed I assumed the OP had got it wrong!!

Comment: In that case, change the first paragraph too, which states "The x axis is frequency in hertz".

Comment: @CamilStaps is it likely the OP is talking about 13.971kHz?

Comment: @CamilStaps sorry dude (heh heh) I was taken up in the content and didn't notice it was you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks to me like two unrelated [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sideband_modulation) signals, with a carrier that happens to be in the middle. It could be coincidence, or perhaps this is a pilot carrier to make tuning easier. Were you able to listen to what was being said? That could be a big clue.

Here's another USB waterfall sample:

[image: USB waterfall]

(many more good samples at [source](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/tag/upper-side-band/))

The asymmetrical shape, and the concentration of power at the low end, corresponding to the \$f_1\$ [formants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant) of human speech, gives it away.

Comment: Maybe two people are talking to each other on adjacent channels.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a wild guess, but it might be a [WSPR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSPR_%28amateur_radio_software%29) signal. Low-power FSK data.

Comment: definately not WSPR. WSPR is 4 tones at about 1.5 Hz spacing. It looks like a carrier unless you look very closely, and it transmits only intermittently.